# Calculating linear velocity

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

I have the question

> Use the answer to question 1 to calculate the linear velocity of a point on the surface of the Earth (radius of Earth = $6.4 \times 10^6$ [m]).

So the answer for question 1 was $7.3 \times 10^{-5}$ [rads$^{-1}$].

Now using this is question 2 I know that the formula for linear velocity is $V = rw$.

So $V = 6.4 \times 10^6 m \times 7.3 \times 10^{-5} rads^{-1}$

Therefore V = 467.2 [radms$^{-1}$].

However, I do not know if the units for the final answer are correct.

Comment: usually the velocity is measured in units of distance per units of time. You got time in the denominator but numerator looks unexpected to me. Perhaps I don't understand your notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rad is essentially a dimensionless unit. So $\omega R$ has dimensions of velocity.

Comment: Ah I see. So basically rad has no units so it's just left with meters m and seconds s. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Do accept the answer if you feel your query has been resolved.